# Spree: Change view depending on the taxon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, spree, parameters

I'm customizing a spree application and i'm stuck trying to change my views depending on which taxon i am.

I have two "major" taxons, which are: "registries" and "categories". And these taxons have different views.

Taxons#show:

```
def show
  @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
  return unless @taxon
  @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
  @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
end
```

References:

[Render a rails partial based on the id of an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349350/render-a-rails-partial-based-on-the-id-of-an-action)

[Rendering rails partial with dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365474/rendering-rails-partial-with-dynamic-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand your question but still, you have two major Taxons 'a' & 'b' and you want to change the view

if its matter of just view like style sheet you can use following in ActionView

```
<%if current_page?('/t/registries')%> 
<!--something-->  
<%end%>
```

if you want to change complete template through controller

```
def show
  @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
  if @taxon.name == "registries"
     redirect_to 'name_of_custom_action_for_the_desired_view'
  end
  #and you can fetch products and taxonomies in the view
end
```

hope the answer was helpful